# RAILS 4/Sidekiq in production: An SMTP To address is required to send a message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sidekiq, sendgrid

This question has been asked before many times and the answer is that a valid email address (SENDER) needs to be used to SEND emails from your Rails app. However, I am still getting this error. Here is my production configuration

```
ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 'mypersonalemailaddress@gmail.com'

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
host = 'https://peaceful-cove-8372.herokuapp.com'
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host =>  'https://www.myapp.org' }
```

I have my own personal email address specified but still get this error. I think I am failing to undertand how this works. I should add, that my development configuration works just fine using this email address. Any thoughts?

Worker log error is:

```
    ResponseWorker JID-f1abef7152aca07b829ac16c DEBUG: Failure! Retry 1 in 64 seconds
    2015-07-27T16:21:02.377105+00:00 app[worker.1]: 3 TID-ov5xeb7p0 
     WARN:  {"class"=>"ResponseWorker", "args"=>[71], "retry"=>5, "queue"=>"default",  
    "jid"=>"f1abef7152aca07b829ac16c", "created_at"=>1438014039.1775503,
    "enqueued_at"=>1438014061.402422, "error_message"=>"An SMTP To address 
    is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, 
    or bcc address.", "error_class"=>"ArgumentError", 
    "failed_at"=>1438014040.0273588, "retry_count"=>1, "retried_at"=>1438014062.3470724}
```

Here is an example of a method in my MicropostMailer

```
def notify_question_followers_of_response(micropost, response, follower)
     @response = response
     @micropost = micropost
     @email = follower.email
     @follower = follower
     @notification = follower.notification
     mail to: @email, subject: "#{@response.user.full_name} wrote an answer to a question you follow: \"#{@micropost.content}\""
end
```

I can't see the problem here......of course, I'm fairly new. I don't understand why it works fine in development and not in production....

Comment: Could you write down the exact error that appears ? If this is in the title of your question, it says `To Address` and not `From Address`, so the problem is not here.

Comment: Added as asked. Thanks for your time

Comment: The configuration settings you have listed above are not the problem. You need to show the Rails code where you are setting the *to* email address i.e. the intended _receiver_ of the email.

Comment: You will need to do some debugging. E.g. check the `follower` parameter in the method you have in the question above using something like: `logger.info "Emailing: #{follower.inspect}"`.